How can I use jQuery on Bootstrap navbar to scroll into section on another page?
I have a website which uses Bootstrap navbar and jQuery to scroll between a few sections (in index1.html).
Now I added another page to the website (index2.html), but if i use jQuery smooth scroll
the only problem I have now is when attempting to do that from different page. What I mean by that is if I click on a link in a page, it should load the new page and then scroll to the specific div element
Here is the code I used to scrolling inside the page:
// Find the navbar menu link
   let topMenu = $(".navbar-nav"),
   topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
  
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a")
  
  // Bind click handler to menu items
  // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
   menuItems.click(function(e){
       let href = $(this).attr("href"),
           offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight - 80;

       $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
           scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 500);

       e.preventDefault();
   }); 

      


You can do the same, except give the href a full URL to the other page, including the # part. You can then check for window.location.hash when the page has loaded and then scroll to that element.

Can you give me an example of your solutions?

Well the answer is closed so can't really post a code example. But don't you see the code where you check $(this).attr("href")? You can just do the same for window.location.hash. Check the linked answer in the box above.
